# android sms receiver get imsi and sms receiver mobile number in dual sim devices

Tags: android, kotlin

In dual sim devices, when I send sms to sim number 1(from other device) I want to get the sim IMSI and slot index and mobile number of the receiver sim (not the "originatingAddress"),  I used the `bundle.getInt("subscription")` to get the slot index but it returns wrong numbers like 17 and 13

Kotlin code

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.provider.Telephony
import android.telephony.SmsMessage
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager
import android.util.Log

class SmsReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    companion object {
        private val TAG by lazy { SmsReceiver::class.java.simpleName }
        private var imsi: String? = null
        private var originatingAddress: String? = null
        private var displayMessageBody: String? = null
        private var slotIndex = 0
    }

    @SuppressLint("HardwareIds", "UnsafeProtectedBroadcastReceiver", "MissingPermission")
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive")
        val bundle = intent?.extras ?: return
        slotIndex = bundle.getInt("subscription")

        if (context != null) {
            imsi =
                (context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager).createForSubscriptionId(
                    slotIndex
                ).subscriberId
        }
        try {

            val pdusObj = bundle.get("pdus") as Array<*>
            val format = bundle.getString("format")
            val message = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(pdusObj[0] as ByteArray, format)
            originatingAddress = message.originatingAddress
            displayMessageBody = message.displayMessageBody

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception in smsReceiver $e")
        }
    }

}
```